# I'm trying to work out how to update asp code but not refresh the page. (html, ASP and javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic, refresh, reload

So this is quite a strange problem, but basically I have a server which can read data out of a PLC using its own asp instructions.  You can create your own webpage to put on the server which can use these asp instructions.  So I have some very basic html code with some javascript and a few asp instructions in it to get data from the PLC.  The values in the PLC are constantly changing and I would like the page to keep updating these values.  I tried using meta reload but the screen flicks and it's not very nice.  I also tried using java script to refresh after an interval and I managed to get a counter working without having to update the whole page, but the asp wouldn't update (appears you need to reload the page to refresh the asp values).  Is there any way to request the server to refresh the asp values, without having to reload the actual webpage? Or is there a better way of doing this altogether?
Here is some code I tried so you can see basically what is going on:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = setupDataRefresh;
function setupDataRefresh() {
  setInterval("refreshData();",100);
}
function refreshData() {
  document.getElementById("Tag0").innerHTML="<% ReadLogixTag("1,0","doLight","BOOL");%>";
}
</script>
```

In the code above, the asp code ReadLogixTag is specific to the server device.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: No, ASP is server-sided, so what you write in `.asp` will first be parsed by IIS and then distributed to browsers in plain, executed text. If you need to dynamically update your web page with server side value, use AJAX, or at least hidden `iframe`.

Answer (score 1):

have a look [here](http://ajaxed.org/) it's a great library - basically it is an implementation of the php xajax in classic asp.

you could do this by yourself but ajaxed has some useful other classes in it...

basically you do a ajax request in your javascript method refreshData() (with jQuery for example). on the serverside ReadLogixTag() is executed and sends html code back to the client.

example (with jQuery and without ajaxed):

```
<%

if request.form("ajax") = true then
  call ReadLogixTag( Request.Form("param1"), Request.Form("param2"), Request.Form("param3") )
end if

sub ReadLogixTag(param1, param2, param3)
  ' do stuff
  response.write "<b>" & param1 & "</b>"
end sub

%>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = setupDataRefresh;
function setupDataRefresh() {
  setInterval("refreshData();",100);
}
function refreshData() {
  $.post("myASPPage.asp", {
    ajax: true,
    param1: "1,0",
    param2: "doLight",
    param3: "BOOL"
  }, function(data) {
    $("#Tag0").html(data);
  });
}
</script>

<div id="Tag0"></div>
```